# ComboBox cannot convert from KeyValuePair to Integer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, keyvaluepair

I am getting a DataBinding error where my ComboBox are binded to a `KeyValuePair` list and the value stored to the `DataBase` is an integer.

How do I go about converting it?

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub SetupeCombo()
     Dim comboSource = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))

     For Each o In _List
          comboSource.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer,String)(o.ID, o.Details))
     Next

     comboBox1.DisplayMember = NameOf(Table.Details)
     comboBox1.ValueMember =  NameOf(Table.ID)
     comboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(comboSource, Nothing)
End Sub
```

```
Public Sub BindComboBox()
     Dim comboBoxBindings = comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(NameOf(ComboBox.SelectedValue), dataSource, NameOf(dataSource.ID), True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, String.Empty)        
     AddHandler comboBoxBindings.BindingComplete, AddressOf comboBoxBindings _BindingComplete
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub comboBoxBindings_BindingComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As BindingCompleteEventArgs)
      If e.BindingCompleteState <> BindingCompleteState.Success Then MessageBox.Show("Test: " & e.ErrorText)
End Sub
```

**Error**

> Test: Value[1, TestValue] cannot be converted to a type 'ID'

Comment: Why don't you use what's in `_List` or `Table` (it's not clear what is the source of the data) as the DataSource of your BindingSource? So you can use the fields' names directly when setting the `DisplayMember` and the bindings. It looks like you're making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue by using a custom ComboBox `Class`. Inside my DTO I created a `String` property which returns a combined value of ID (Integer) and Description (String).

Using this property I was able to set the `DisplayMember` and the `ValueMember` was set to the ID field which the DataBinding also used. So no casting was required in the end.

Example:

```
Public Class ComboBox
    Public Property Details As String
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Property Display() As String
        Get 
            Return $"{ID}: {Details}"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

And after modifying my `SetupCombo` method.

```
Private Sub SetupeCombo()
     Dim comboSource = _list.Select(Function(x) New CombBox With{
                                  .ID = x.ID, 
                                  .Details = x.Details})
                            .ToList()   

     comboBox1.DisplayMember = NameOf(ComboBox.Display)
     comboBox1.ValueMember =  NameOf(ComboBox.ID)
     comboBox1.DataSource = comboSource
End Sub
```

Finally my DataBinding

```
Public Sub BindComboBox()
     Dim comboBoxBindings = comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(NameOf(ComboBox.SelectedValue), dataSource, NameOf(ComboBox.ID), True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, String.Empty)        
     AddHandler comboBoxBindings.BindingComplete, AddressOf comboBoxBindings _BindingComplete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Should that not be

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value"
comboBox1.ValueMember =  "Key"
```

instead, as you are adding KeyValuePairs?

Comment: Yes but then how do I specify the `Key` when am setting the `DataBindings`?

Comment: I hardly use BindingSource, can't you just set ```comboBox1.DataSource = comboSource```?